# Atomic Increment Performance in SMP systems

Tags: kernel, solaris

I am interested in knowing which one the following methods of incrementing a global counter in the kernel will be most optimal in SMP systems? By optimal, I mean less amount of time taken as well as less CPU cycles spent.

mutex_enter(mutex)

counter++

mutex_exit(mutex)

AND,

atomic_inc(counter)

mutex_enter, mutex_exit and atomic_inc(3C) are from Solaris 10 (sparc).

Thanks,

Saurav

Answer (score 1):

atomic_inc() should be the fastest if it directly translates to a CPU instruction. If not, it should not be worse than mutex-guarded counter++.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I looked into the open solaris code for the assembly implementation, and it also hints that atomic_inc should be faster.